# Error by starting FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, noclassdeffounderror, android-fragmentactivity

I want to change my project from Activity to FragmentActivity. The first step was to create the fragment:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

the detail_fragment is a simple LinearLayout with a TextView

The second Step was to (after my SplashScreen) make the parent class to FragmentActivity:

```
public class TestFrag extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frag_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The R.layout.frag_main:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frag"
    android:name=".fragments.Frag1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

On my SplashScreen is say know:

```
Intent myInt = new Intent(this, TestFrag.class);
startActivity(myInt);
```

But alwas i get these errors:

```
05-18 23:09:51.543: W/dalvikvm(28644): Unable to resolve superclass of Lws/stefma/projectname/TestFrag; (20)
05-18 23:09:51.543: W/dalvikvm(28644): Link of class 'Lws/stefma/projectname/TestFrag;' failed
05-18 23:09:51.543: E/dalvikvm(28644): Could not find class 'ws.stefma.projectname.TestFrag', referenced from method ws.stefma.projectname.Activity_Login_Registration.onCreate
05-18 23:09:51.543: W/dalvikvm(28644): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 94 (Lws/stefma/projectname/TestFrag;) in Lws/stefma/projectname/Activity_Login_Registration;
05-18 23:09:51.543: D/dalvikvm(28644): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000b
05-18 23:09:51.583: D/AndroidRuntime(28644): Shutting down VM
05-18 23:09:51.583: W/dalvikvm(28644): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41850930)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ws.stefma.projectname.TestFrag
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at ws.stefma.projectname.Activity_Login_Registration.onCreate(Activity_Login_Registration.java:30)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-18 23:09:51.593: E/AndroidRuntime(28644):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no idea why... 
The confused about that:
If I go back from `FragmentActivity` to `Activity` all runs fine without errors!!!

Also i have these in my AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="ws.stefma.projectname.TestFrag" />
```

**Update:**

I have import the `support-v4 libary`. 
My `AndroidManifest` was declared to `minSdk="14"` and `targetSdk="17"`. 
Because i used the support-v4 I have imported on the Fragment-Class

```
import android.app.support.v4.Fragment
```

Now i have changed that to

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

and it seems to work...

Also i must change the `FragmentActivity` to `Activity`. Because the `FragmentActivity` is only an Class for the support v4 Package!

**Update 2** - Solution found:
[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633026/1231245)

Comment: What are your minSdk, targetSdk?  Are you using the Compatibility Package?

Comment: I have minSdk="14" and tagetSdk="17". Also I have Imported Support-v4 Package and want use them...

Comment: It doesn't make sence, because minSdk is 14. If you have minSdk less than 11, you'll need this library. Fragment was come at API v11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, here is the Solution.
I donn't know exactly what the folling stands for and what it makes, but it runs and i have now errors after these workaround:

`Close eclipse` -> `remove support-V4` -> `open eclipse` -> `right click on your project` -> `AndroidTools` -> `Add Support Libary` -> `right click on your project` -> `Properties` -> `Choose java build path` -> `Choose 'Order and Export'` -> `Select All` -> `Click 'ok'` -> `Project` -> `Clean` -> `Run and stay happy!`

Comment: Please, checkout minSdk version.

Answer (score 0):

Change R.layout.frag_main to something like:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
           android:id="@+id/fragment1"
           android:name="ws.stefma.projectname.Frag1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change nothing. Same error. I have updatet to SDK rev. 22 and Support Libary to rev. 13... Maybe is there an error?

Comment: If Stefan changes API version to 8, it won't works. The best way to use FrameLayout and load fragment to this placeholder into Activity.onCreate.

Comment: For API version 8 you need the support library. I am also using API 8 and static fragments work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need use support-v4 library. Please tell me why do you use that library? I see min sdk is 14, in this case using of sopport-v4 is useless.

Please checkout ws.stefma.projectname package, because logcat says that ws.stefma.projectname.TestFrag doesn't exist.

Comment: I've want to use the new DrawerLayout (http://x.co/17W32). But it seems it is only available at support-v4... How can i import that without the error?!